# Increasing the height of the Beamer footline

Tags: tables, beamer, header-footer, themes

When I add a `tabular`environment to the `footline` of my presentation, only the first line is shown. How can I increase the heigth of the footline to show the whole table?

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
{
\tiny\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}}
First line & John Doe & fsdfs\\ 
second line \& Title of the talk & dsdfsd\\
some third line & & 
\end{tabular}
}}

\frame{
\frametitle{fdfsdgdf}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to patch the `\beamer@calculateheadfoot` command (defined in the file `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`) to add some space for the new footline:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@calculateheadfoot}{\advance\footheight by 4pt}{\advance\footheight by 20pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.5ex,dp=20pt,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}
\tiny\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.38\textwidth}@{}}
First line & John Doe & fsdfs\\ 
second line \& Title of the talk & dsdfsd\\
some third line & & 
\end{tabular}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Test Frame}
\lipsum[4]
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also added a `beamercolorbox` to the definition, but this is completely optional.

Comment: This answer also works really well when the template puts a logo at the bottom and you want `\allowframebreaks` to break sooner so as to not overlap the logo (I am allowing frame breaks for a bibliography only).

Answer (score 0):

With the [current beamer development version](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/e5c868041cb51c278420d0b4189693ed569ee3d9) (should be included in beamer v3.70 or newer), beamer now recalculates the head- and footheight at the start of each frame, so you can use your code as it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
{
\tiny\begin{tabular}{p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.25\textwidth}p{0.45\textwidth}}
First line & John Doe & fsdfs\\ 
second line \& Title of the talk & dsdfsd\\
some third line & & 
\end{tabular}
}}

\frame{
\frametitle{fdfsdgdf}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]