# Reduce hight of footer in beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, footer, beamer-metropolis

I would like to reduce the height of my footer in beamer. I tried `\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{0}{0}\selectfont}` but at one point, this doesn't reduce the height anymore. Also, it would be nice if the text in the footer would vertically align with the slide title. Here my code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} 
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]

\title{My Title}
\subtitle{My Subtitle}
\author{My Name}
\date{}
\institute{Reference}

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertauthor\hfill\insertsubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{0}{0}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=black}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Contents}\vspace{3pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First Point
\item Second Point
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to chec out https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/105753/196228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the font size to 0 does not help because the font is not available in this size and will be replaced with the next bigger size, which is 3pt.

To reduce the height of the footline, you can instead adjust the padding of the beamer box:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\title{My Title}
\subtitle{My Subtitle}
\author{My Name}
\date{}
\institute{Reference}

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertauthor\hfill\insertsubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{0}{0}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=black}


\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth, sep=1ex]{footline}%
    \hspace{0.3cm}
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate*{frame footer}
    \hfill%
    \usebeamertemplate*{page number in head/foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Contents}\vspace{3pt}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First Point
\item Second Point
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I did add `\hspace{0.3cm}` after frame numbering, but I managed to to that myself:-)